# Oracle SQL Calculating Variance

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Lets say I have a table like so:

```
ID         TYPE          MONTH       AMOUNT         
--         ----          ----          ---          

abc        Forecast       1           150          
def        Forecast       1           225          
abc        Budget         1           140          
def        Budget         1           250         
abc        Forecast       2           190          
abc        Budget         2           450
```

What I want to do is insert a record for each ID that is the difference between the Forecast and the Budget for each month.  So result would look like this:

```
ID         TYPE          MONTH       AMOUNT         
--         ----          ----          ---          

abc        Forecast       1           150          
def        Forecast       1           225          
abc        Budget         1           140          
def        Budget         1           250         
abc        Forecast       2           190          
abc        Budget         2           450 
abc        Variance       1           10
abc        Variance       2          -260
def        Variance       1          -25
```

could someone please provide the SQL for this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the difference and insert the variance rows. (This assumes each id,month combination has Forecast and Budget rows. If not, add `else 0` in each `max`)

```
insert into tbl(id,type,month,amount)
select id,'Variance',month,
max(case when type='Forecast' then amount end) - max(case when type='Budget' then amount end) 
from tbl
group by id,month
```

Comment: one question  .. why would you use 'max' instead of 'sum'?

Comment: if you have multiple rows, you can use `sum` to subtract the summed values. as the question showed one row per id,month i used `max`..you could've also used `sum` or `min`. use `else 0` with `sum`.